# The sequence $(x_n)$ : $x_{n+2}=\frac{x_{n+1}\sqrt{x_n^2+1}+x_{n}\sqrt{x_{n+1}^2+1}-x_n-x_{n+1}}{x_{n+1}x_n-(\sqrt{x_{n+1}^2+1}-1)(\sqrt{x_n^2+1}-1)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

The sequence $(x_n)$ is defined by the formula:
$$\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
x_1=1, x_2=\sqrt{3}\\
x_{n+2}=\frac{x_{n+1}\sqrt{x_n^2+1}+x_{n}\sqrt{x_{n+1}^2+1}-x_n-x_{n+1}}{x_{n+1}x_n-\big(\sqrt{x_{n+1}^2+1}-1\big)\big(\sqrt{x_{n}^2+1}-1\big)}, \quad n=1,2,3\dots
\end{array} \right.$$
Find $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}x_n$.

I see:
$$\begin{array}{rl}
x_{n+2}&=\frac{x_{n+1}\sqrt{x_n^2+1}+x_{n}\sqrt{x_{n+1}^2+1}-x_n-x_{n+1}}{x_{n+1}x_n-\big(\sqrt{x_{n+1}^2+1}-1\big)\big(\sqrt{x_{n}^2+1}-1\big)}\\
&=\frac{x_{n}\big(\sqrt{x_{n+1}^2+1}-1 \big)+x_{n+1}\big(\sqrt{x_{n}^2+1}-1 \big)}{x_{n+1}x_n-\frac{x_n^2x_{n+1}^2}{\big(\sqrt{x_{n+1}^2+1}+1\big)\big(\sqrt{x_{n}^2+1}+1\big)}}\\
&=\frac{x_{n+1}\big(\sqrt{x_{n}^2+1}+1\big)+x_{n}\big(\sqrt{x_{n+1}^2+1}+1\big)}{\big(\sqrt{x_{n+1}^2+1}+1\big)\big(\sqrt{x_{n}^2+1}+1\big)-x_nx_{n+1}}
\end{array}$$
That's all I can do. So, I hope hints from you. Thank you.

Comment: Where does the problem come form? Homework, a contest, ...? – I would guess that the substitution $x_n = \sinh(y_n)$ simplifies things ...

Comment: Hello :) If $(x_n)_n$ converges, let $x$ be its limit. We have $x_{n+2}=f(x_n,x_{n+1})$, where the RHS $f$ is continuous. Hence, $x=f(x,x)$. Maybe, you can solve this equation.

Comment: @Jochen: I know that, but how to prove $(x_n)$ is converges. That's I don't know.

Comment: @Martin R: It is a exe that I accidentally found

Comment: I found that $x_n = \tan \theta_n$ yields $\tan \theta_{n+2} = \tan\frac{\theta_n + \theta_{n+1}}{2}$. Calculation is somewhat tedious so I'm not sure, but it would solve the problem.

Comment: Intuition for this substitution is from terms $\sqrt{1+x_n^2}$; Note that $1+ \tan^2{\theta} = \sec^2\theta$. @MartinR 's comment would be from the similar observation and $1+ \sinh^2{y} = \cosh^2{y}$.

Comment: @dust05 The two first terms confirm that your substitution is adequate: $\tan \pi/4=1$, $\tan \pi/3=\sqrt{3}$...

Comment: I'm very curious to know where this comes from, BTW

Comment: @Jochen Good idea but it leads to the identity $a = a$ which does not help in calculating $a$.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze Thank you, i didn't realized that.

Answer (score 4):

By rationalising the denominator, $x_{n+2}$ simplifies to $$\frac{\sqrt{x_n^2+1}\sqrt{x_{n+1}^2+1}+x_nx_{n+1}-1}{x_n+x_{n+1}}.$$

Letting $$x_n=\frac12\left(p_n-\frac1{p_n}\right),$$ that is (say) $$p_n=x_n+\sqrt{x_n^2+1}$$ and simplifying further, you get $$x_{n+2}=\frac{p_np_{n+1}-1}{p_n+p_{n+1}}$$

So, if $p_n=\cot\theta_n$, then $$x_{n+2}=\cot(\theta_n+\theta_{n+1}).$$

Furthermore, $$x_n=\frac12\left(\cot\theta_n-\frac1{\cot\theta_n}\right)=\cot{2\theta_n}.$$

It follows that $2\theta_{n+2}=\theta_n+\theta_{n+1},$ so that you can solve for $\theta_n$ explicitly from the initial conditions. The solution is
$$\frac{2\theta_2+\theta_1}{3}+\frac{4\theta_2-4\theta_1}{3}\left(-\frac12\right)^n,$$ which has limit $$\frac{2\theta_2+\theta_1}{3}$$.

You know that $\cot2\theta_1=1$ and $\cot2\theta_2=\sqrt{3}$, so that $\theta_1=\frac\pi8$ and $\theta_2=\frac\pi{12}$. Therefore, the limit of $\theta_n$ is $\frac{7\pi}{72}$, and so the limit of $x_n$ is $\cot\frac{7\pi}{36}$.